# How can I get my program to return -1/4 and NOT 1/-4?

Tags: java, class

\Help! My homework is due by 12am tonight and I can't seem to get my program to output a negative number as -1/4 rather than 1/-4! It's frustrating me because the thing is, I cannot just place a "-" in front of my numbers (which as you can see in my program below, I have commented out). 
My attempt at getting fraction to be -1/4 (just using this fraction as an example) is under the "public RationalNumber(int...) { line: you see the part where I have *-1 written? Where did I go wrong in that step that led me to get 1/-4? This is frustrating me... Thanks in advance.

```
private int n;
private int d;      
public RationalNumber(int numerator, int denominator) {
    if (denominator == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }               
    if (denominator < 0) {
        denominator = denominator * -1;
        numerator = numerator * -1;          
      }
    n = numerator;
    d = denominator;        
    simplified();
}   

public RationalNumber add(RationalNumber rn) {
    int comDenom = d * rn.getDenominator(); 
    int num1 = n * rn.d;
    int num2 = rn.n * d;
    d = comDenom;
    return new RationalNumber(num1 + num2, d);      
}

public RationalNumber subtract(RationalNumber rn) {
    int num1 = n * rn.d;
    int num2 = rn.n * d;
    return new RationalNumber(num1 - num2, d);
}

public RationalNumber multiply(RationalNumber rn) {
    int numer = n * rn.n;
    int denom = d * rn.d;
    return new RationalNumber(numer, denom);
}

public RationalNumber divide(RationalNumber rn) {
    int numer = n * rn.d;
    int denom = d * rn.n;
    return new RationalNumber(numer, denom);
}   

public RationalNumber() {
    n = 0;
    d = 1;
}

public boolean equals(RationalNumber o) {
    return (n == o.getNumerator() && d == o.getDenominator());
}   

public int getDenominator() {
    return d;
}

public int getNumerator() {
    return n;
}   

public String toString() { //Prints everything here.
    if (d == 1) {
        return "" + n;
    }       
    if (n == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    /*if ((n < 0) || (d < 0)) {
        return "-" + Math.abs(n) + "/" + Math.abs(d);
    }*/
    return n + "/" + d;
}   

private void simplified() {
     if (n != 0) {
         int cDenom = gcd(n, d);
         n = n / cDenom;
         d = d / cDenom;
     }
}   

private int gcd(int gcdNum1, int gcdNum2) {
    while (gcdNum1 != 0 && gcdNum2 != 0) {
        int tempNum = gcdNum2;
        gcdNum2 = gcdNum1 % gcdNum2;
        gcdNum1 = tempNum;
    }
    return gcdNum1 + gcdNum2;
}
```

Comment: i think both values are same

Comment: what is the problem with -1/4 for u

Comment: I know they are the same, but my assignment requires me to return -1/4.

Comment: Can `gcd` return a negative number? What happens if it does?

Comment: I haven't tried that...where should I implement the "-"?

Comment: It looks as though your `add()` method will modify the `d` member of the object it's called on. This is probably not something you want. (It's also probably not causing this bug, but it'll cause other issues.)

Comment: What does it print if you remove the comments in the `toString()` method?

Comment: @user000001, it will return the correct answer, however, I'm not supposed to return a "-" within the toString( )...just the "0" and n are allowed to be returned in this method

Comment: You should never used one letter for a variable name. Follow Java naming conventions: http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: @user1029481 The problem is in the gcd method. See answer

Comment: Thank you! I realized that I should've took its absolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `gcd()` method may return a negative result. When you call the `simplified()` method, you divide `n` and `c` with a possibly negative number, and you change their sign. To fix it, you can change the `gcd()` method to return always a positive result.

Change this line:

```
return gcdNum1 + gcdNum2;
```

to

```
if (gcdNum1 + gcdNum2 < 0) {
    return -(gcdNum1 + gcdNum2);
} else {
    return gcdNum1 + gcdNum2;
}
```

And then check if you get the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is homework, it is in your best interest to find and fix the problem yourself.

Here are a couple of hints to get you started:

- Figure out what the values of `n` and `d` are before and after the constructor calls `simplified()`.
- You could do this with your Java IDE's debugger, or by using trace prints; i.e. calls to `System.out.println(...)`

Comment: I've debugged it myself and all answers are correct except where the "-" is placed.

Answer (score 1):

You could put back in the commented out section of your `toString` method, just make it an XOR (^) rather than OR (||)

Answer (score 0):

```
return n + "/" + d;
```

Change to:

```
return ((n>=0 && d>=0) || (n<0 && d<0))?(""):("-")+Math.abs(n)+"/"+Math.abs(d);
```

Just a simple work around.